# Solve the following systems of equations ( Matrices)

Tags: matrices

Solve the following systems of equations:

\begin{Bmatrix}
       x_1 & -x_2 & -x_3 & +0x_4 & = 2 \\
        -x_1 & +2x_2 & +0x_3 & +3x_4 &= 1 \\
        x_1 & +0x_2 & +x_3 & +0x_4 & =5\\
        \end{Bmatrix}

I try to make a zero triangle but always reach a step where I'm in a cycle trying to do the same thing over and over. I once got $x_3=1/3$

Working: 
1-

\begin{Bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & -1 & +0 &  2 \\
        -1 & +2 & +0 & +3 & 1 \\
        1 & +0 & +1 & +0 & 5\\
        \end{Bmatrix}

2- Eq2 to Eq2 + Eq1

\begin{Bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & -1 & +0 &  2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 3 \\
        1 & +0 & +1 & +0 & 5\\
        \end{Bmatrix}

3- Eq3 to Eq3 + Eq1

\begin{Bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & -1 & +0 &  2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3\\
        \end{Bmatrix}

4- Eq3 to Eq3 - Eq2

\begin{Bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & -1 & +0 &  2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
        \end{Bmatrix}

Now I can say $3x_3=1$

Thus, $x_3=1/3$

After that i tried but couldn't complete...

Any suggestions would be appreciated

**EDIT: The last step is incorrect.**

It should be :

\begin{Bmatrix}
       1 & -1 & -1 & +0 &  2 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & -3 & 0\\
        \end{Bmatrix}

So what I did next is:

From Third Row: $x_3+x_4=0$

so, $x_4=-x_3$

Then, From the Second row:

$x_2-x_3+3x_4=3$

$x_2-x_3+3(-x_3)=3$

$x_2-x_3=3$

$x_2=3+x_3$

And I stopped

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried everything... I once got that $x_3=1/3$ and that's it. I always reach a step where i can no longer make the elements zero

Comment: Please post your working up to the point where you got stuck, then I'm sure someone can help you to get further.

Comment: @David done posting the working

Comment: $x_4$ can be chosen arbitary. There are infinite many solutions.

Comment: $$\pmatrix{5\\3\\0\\0}+t\pmatrix{-1\\-2\\1\\1}$$ is the general solution.

Comment: The last step is incorrect. The last row in the last matrix must be $0\ 0\ 3\ -3\ 0 \ $

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your working is correct, haven't checked it.

You have found an echelon form for your system, now you need to proceed to **back substitution**.  This means that you work out what you can say about the last variable, then the second last and so on.  In your case, $x_4$ then $x_3$ and so on.

Note that none of the rows in your echelon form gives any direct information about $x_4$.  (For example, the second row says $x_2-x_3+3x_4=3$, but as you don't yet know $x_2$ and $x_3$, you can't find $x_4$.)  Therefore, $x_4$ could be any number whatever, and it is usual to write it as a **parameter**, say
$$x_4=t\ .$$
Now from your third row, $3x_3+0x_4=1$, so
$$x_3=\frac13\ .$$
The second row says $x_2-x_3+3x_4=3$, so $x_2=3+x_3-3x_4$, and substituting in the known values gives
$$x_2=\frac{10}3-3t\ .$$
You can then use the first row to solve for $x_1$ in terms of $t$, please try it.

In the end, you will have formulae for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ in terms of the parameter $t$, which could be anything.  These formulae give infinitely many solutions of the system.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

when i row reduce your matrix $\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&0&2\\-1&2&0&3&1\\1&0&1&0&5}$ 
 i get $\pmatrix{1&0&0&1&5\\0&1&0&2&3\\0&0&1&-1&0}.$

let us call the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $x_4$ corresponding to the four columns. the fourth variable $x_4$ is called the free variable. to find a particular solution we set it to zero. you get a particular solution $x_1 = 5, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 0, x_4 = 0.$

to find the homogeneous solution we the free variable to one and delete the last column. so we $x_1 = -1, x_2 = -2, x_3 = 1, x_4 = 1.$

then general solution is $x_g = x_p + tx_h.$ in component form you have $$x_1 = 5-t, x_2 = 3-2t, x_3 = t, x_4 = t \text{ where $t$ is any real number.}$$

Comment: No, because there are 5 rows. If there were 4 only i would have known.

Comment: @Mr.Mohamed, you mean five columns.

Comment: What was your second step? I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

You should now do backwards elimination; first divide the third equation by $3$ and add the third equation to the second and the first, getting
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 7/3\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 10/3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now add the second equation to the first one:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 17/3\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 10/3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now you know that you can give $x_4$ any value, say $x_4=h$, and determine consequently the other unknowns:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=\frac{17}{3}-3h\\
x_2=\frac{10}{3}-3h\\
x_3=\frac{1}{3}\\
x_4=h
\end{cases}
$$